# Compile error when using Scoreloop UI as a module in Intellij IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea, scoreloop

In my Android project, I need to use ScoreloopUI as a module.

It works fine in Eclipse, but I want to use Intellij IDEA.

It works fine if I create a project containing only the module.

I've imported Scoreloop UI as a module, added Android facet, check the "Library Module" box, and added the module dependancy in my project.

When I run, rebuild, or make, it tries to make Scoreloop UI module first, I have a complicated compilation error :

```
java: An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.6.0_24). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
java: java.lang.NullPointerException
java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Code.width(Code.java:276)
java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.initParameterNames(ClassReader.java:1542)
...
java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:133)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain.compile(JavacMain.java:135)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compileJava(JavaBuilder.java:313)
...
java:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'ScoreloopUI'
Compilation completed with 1 error and 5 warnings in 8 sec
1 error
5 warnings
java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error
```

Any idea ?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection... and as a workaround: use eclipse compiler in Intellij (Settings > Compiler > Java

Comment: The result is the same : `java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error`. What make me thinks more about a configuration problem.

Comment: Does it happen with JDK 1.7 set as a target? Does it help if you disable [external build](http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/3550/20121206235318.png)?

Comment: Same error with JDK 1.7. And same error after disabling external build...

Answer (score 1):

In your project  _ build path, have you tried to reorder the compilation units ?

Comment: The result is still the same.